# SAS Proc IML Optimization

Tags: optimization, sas, proc, sas-iml

```
proc iml;  
start f_prob(beta) global(one_m_one, pone_m_one);

p = nrow(one_m_one);
td = j(p,3,0.);
a = 1;
do i = 1 to p;
    td[i,1] = exp((one_m_one[i,1])*(beta[1]) + (one_m_one[i,2])*(beta[2]) + (one_m_one[i,3])*(beta[3]) + (one_m_one[i,4])*(beta[4]) + (one_m_one[i,5])*(beta[5]) + (one_m_one[i,6])*(beta[6]) + (one_m_one[i,7])*(beta[7]) + (one_m_one[i,8])*(beta[8]) + (one_m_one[i,9])*(beta[9]) + (one_m_one[i,10])*(beta[10]));
    do j = a to 11+a;
        td[i,2] = td[i,2] + exp((pone_m_one[j,1])*(beta[1]) + (pone_m_one[j,2])*(beta[2]) + (pone_m_one[j,3])*(beta[3]) + (pone_m_one[j,4])*(beta[4]) + (pone_m_one[j,5])*(beta[5]) + (pone_m_one[j,6])*(beta[6]) + (pone_m_one[j,7])*(beta[7]) + (pone_m_one[j,8])*(beta[8]) + (pone_m_one[j,9])*(beta[9]) + (pone_m_one[j,10])*(beta[10]));
    end;
    a = a + 12;
end;
td[,3] = td[,1]/td[,2];
f = 1;
do i = 1 to p;
    f = f*td[i,3];
end;
return(f);

finish f_prob;

/* Set up the constraints: sum(x)=0 */
/*     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 SIGN VALUE */
con = {.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .    .,  /* specify lower bounds */
       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .    .,  /* specify upper bounds */
       1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0    0}; /* constraints */


beta0 = j(1,10,0);
optn = {1,4};

call nlpnra(rc, result, "f_prob", beta0, optn) blc=con;
```

Hi, I am trying to optimise the function f that has 10 parameters in it with a constraint of all 10 parameters sum up to zero.

Can anyone suggest how can I write the code for the last part so that i can optimise f and get the results i want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems odd that in `f_prob` you have a loop over `j` but `j` does not appear in the expression in the loop. Also: do you have `proc optmodel`?

Comment: Oops i have made the changes to include j in the loop. Thanks for pointing it out. Does Proc optmodel work better?

Comment: I have tried, but i m using sas ue and it does not have Proc optmodel

Comment: Whether OPTMODEL or IML work better depends on what you are trying to do. Usually the OPTMODEL syntax is closer to what you might sketch on the board.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides [an example of how to specify a linear constraint matrix](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/68150/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_nonlinearoptexpls_sect015.htm).  For your example, use a 3 x 12 matrix.

- On the first row (columns 1:10) put any lower-bound constraints for the parameters.
- On the second row (columns 1:10) put any upper-bound constraints for the parameters.
- On the third row, put all ones in columns 1:10. Put a 0 in column 11 to indicate the EQUAL sign. Put 0 in the 12th column to indicate the value of the constraint.

The code looks like this:

```
/* Set up the constraints: sum(x)=0 */
/*     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 SIGN VALUE */
con = {.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .    .,  /* specify lower bounds */
       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .    .,  /* specify upper bounds */
       1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0    0}; /* constraints */
call nlpnra(rc, result, "f_prob", beta, optn) blc=con;
```

The last line specifies the coefficients of the matrix expression c*x = 0, where c = {1 1 ... 1} contains the of the third row.

Comment: Hi, i have made some minor changes to my code and added in your suggestion but i m still having this "ERROR: (execution) Invalid operand to operation." problem. What might be the cause of this error? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: In general, you should not edit your question to incorporate the answer. It makes it difficult for future readers to see the original problem and vote up answers. 

You now have a different problem, probably an error in an arithmetic computation. The SAS log should show you the line number where the error occurs.